# Android In-app micropayments with PayPal

Tags: android, paypal, in-app

I'm developing a free Android app and I want to sell a digital service inside the app. The price of this service is 1 €, so the 0.35 € commission of PayPal is just crazy. The solution could be micropayment system (about 0.10 € of commission in PayPal). Is it possible to include a PayPal micropayment inside my app (kind of PayPal in-app micropayment)? How could I do it? In case it is not possible, which other alternatives could you recommend?

Thanks a lot and kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal requires a separate account for micropayments, and their micropayment rate will be charged on all purchases from that account.

[According to their site](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/micropayments), you will need to sign up for a Business Account, then contact support to get the account enabled for their 5cents + 5% micropayment rate.

After that, you can integrate PayPal with your app normally, but using your micropayment-enabled account.

Comment: Thank you so much, Maximillian! It really helped! I've updated my account to a Business one and asked for a micropayments rate. Now, I only have to wait, but is being processed :)